# Mac OS X - Web Sharing

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, webserver, hosting, osx-server

I've enabled web sharing on my Mac OS X (via default Apache installation), and it gives me a web address that I (and supposedly other computers) can use to access my site.

However, when I try to access it from any other computer, except the one hosting it, it gives me an error that "the web-host has stopped responding."  I suppose this means it's at least finding the site, but for some reason can't access it?

Nothing relevant shows in the access.log or error_log file, so I'm pretty stumped as to why this could be happening.  Is there some random setting I need to change somewhere maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some stuff that comes to mind... Basic suggestions..

**Local Firewall**

Check if you're running a Firewall locally - Go to your Security Settings in System Preferences and look around. Note that http and https correspond to ports 80 and 443 by convention.

**Local Network**

Another issue you may not realize factors in is your computer's location on the Internet relative to other machines. Most people don't connect directly to the Internet, but rather have a local network and then a router that serves as the go-between to connect the local network to the Internet. You likely have this kind of setup. So if you're telling a friend to connect to your IP (which may be something like 192.168.1.4), they'll only be able to connect if they're on the same local network (or if you setup port forwarding on your router).